# Woo commerce / storefront - overriding storefront's checkout js file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

On the woo commerce / storefront checkout page there are 2 checkout.min.js files included: the first is woo commerce's own and then there's a second one from storefront. Note that both these files are executed, one doesn't 'override' the other.

I can figure out where the woo commerce checkout.min.js file is included into the page and also how I could override that one. What I can't understand is how to override the storefront js file as I can't find where it is included into the site.

Ideally I'd just like to remove it altogether as the functionality it includes, namely fixing the position of the payment box on the full-width checkout layout, seems to be buggy. You can see the bug by visiting http://woo.cbjdigital.co.uk using a desktop browser with a short and wide window, going to the checkout page, then scrolling down. The payment box rides over the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the bugs you're referring to on Chrome...but you can "dequeue" scripts with [`wp_dequeue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) and then enqueue your own.

```
function dequeue_wc_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_wc_scripts', 100 );
```

You'll need to search your theme for the "handle" you'll need to deregister the second set of checkout scripts.

Comment: Thanks rnevius, that's the problem I have really, I can't find the handle anywhere for the storefront script at:

/wp-content/themes/storefront/js/checkout.min.js